# how to chose the positions text and buttons in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

In the preview I made my app to look like this.

Picture from the preview:

[image: [1]]

unfortunately when I launch the app its look like this

picture from the test

[image: [2]]

And this my page code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="315dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="48dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="287dp">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="212dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="70dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="232dp">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="271dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="70dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="153dp">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="218dp"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="2dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="4dp">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="271dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="70dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="77dp">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="218dp"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:text="Se connecter"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="2dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="4dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="67dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Numero de telephone"
    android:inputType="phone"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="70dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="77dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="274dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Mot de pass"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="70dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="153dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
    android:layout_width="214dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:text="rester connecte"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="70dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="232dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="313dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:text="Se connecter"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="48dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="287dp" />
```

Comment: Why not just use the design tab in Android Studio to create the layout?

Comment: Yes I did make it with the design tab but whene i launch the app its look terrible

Comment: From the code it looks like you aren't using a layout. Try using a Relative Layout and place all elements inside it.

Comment: Oh i didnt Know that thank you i will try now .
And its okay if i put the layout now or i need to remove all the elements

Comment: You should be able to copy and paste all of you current elements into the layout. Then just delete the outer ones.

Comment: Thank you mate for your support

Comment: hi i did what you told me and that didnt work i did delete all elements and placed layouts and placed every element inside a layouts that didnt work too

Comment: Can you update your question with the new xml.

Comment: You may have to redo all of the elements so they work on the layout.

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: There are 5 constraint layouts and none of them have any elements in them.

Comment: But why i did put the element inside it

Comment: Edit the xml code and delete all but one Constraint Layout and copy the code for the elements and put in in between the <> and </> for the constraint layout.

Answer (score 0):

When you use ConstraintLayout you have to add constraints between elements. When you simply drag and drop them using the layout editor it only creates the keys `"tools:layout_editor_absoluteX"` and `"tools:layout_editor_absoluteY"` which are only used within android studio so it knows how to show them in the layout editor.

You can follow this link, to understand how to use ConstraintLayout
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html